# Sentry + CodePush React-Native: Failed to upload AppCenter deployment history

Tags: bash, react-native, sentry, code-push

I have the following script in place to upload CodePush source maps to Sentry

```sh
CODEPUSH_DIST=$(appcenter codepush deployment history $APP_ENV -a $FULL_APP_NAME --output json | jq '.[-1][0]' -r)
RELEASE_NAME="$BUNDLE_ID"@"$APP_BINARY_VERSION"+codepush:"$CODEPUSH_DIST"

echo "CODEPUSH_DIST: " $CODEPUSH_DIST
echo "RELEASE_NAME: " $RELEASE_NAME

sentry-cli react-native appcenter \
  "$APP_NAME" "$PLATFORM" "./build/$PLATFORM/CodePush" \
  --deployment "$APP_ENV" \
  --release-name "$RELEASE_NAME" \
  --dist "$CODEPUSH_DIST" \
  --org "$ORGANIZATION_ID" \
  --project "$APP_NAME"
```

The result is

```sh
CODEPUSH_DIST:  v11
RELEASE_NAME:  com.myappco.myapp.staging@1.0+codepush:v11
> Fetching latest AppCenter deployment info
error: Failed to load AppCenter deployment history
  caused by:
```

So the `RELEASE_NAME` and `CODEPUSH_DIST` are both there.

Why is `sentry-cli` `Fetching latest AppCenter deployment info` again ?

Comment: Can't you just post a reaction-native project on the sentry?

Comment: Why use sentry-cli ??

Comment: @hongdeveloper to automate

Comment: You don't have to suffer like that. It's over as long as you register for Central.

Comment: @hongdeveloper care to elaborate ?